# Silverligt 5 with Ria Wcf Services and Integrated Security

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0, integrated-security

I'm using Integrated Security for my access to BD and Windows Authentication, when it was in development environment and came with my account to my machine (Windows credentials) all queries, inserts and updates worked correctly, connecting to my DB with my Windows credentials.

Now I am releasing my Web Server, so I had to make some adjustments in my query methods in my service put something like:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
public IQueryable<mtto_EmpleadoAdmin> GetMtto_EmpleadoAdmin()
{
    using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.mtto_EmpleadoAdmin;
    }
}
```

And in my web server it works correctly, consultation and brings me all the information

But I don't understand, why my **Insert** and **Update** methods even making changes similar to those I made in my query methods, still do not work

```
 [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
 public void InsertMtto_EmpleadoAdmin(mtto_EmpleadoAdmin mtto_EmpleadoAdmin)
 {
     using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
     {
         if ((mtto_EmpleadoAdmin.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
         {
             this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(mtto_EmpleadoAdmin, EntityState.Added);
         }
         else
         {
             this.ObjectContext.mtto_EmpleadoAdmin.AddObject(mtto_EmpleadoAdmin);
         }
     }

 }
```

I have an error to connect to the BD, because it try make with the web credentials and not with the Windows credentials like must be
Somebody help me?